# Python - Fitting a GEV distribution from these values

Tags: python, plot, distribution

I'm very new with Python and I've looked around on the internet, but couldn't find anything logic that could help me with my problem.

I have values of precipitation in a graph, and now I need to fit a GEV distribution from these values in a graph. Each value equals the maximum value of a year, starting from 1974 to 2017 (so there are 43 values total).

These are the values:

```
max_precip = [9.4, 38.0, 12.5, 35.3, 17.6, 12.9, 12.4, 19.6, 15.0, 13.2, 12.3, 16.9, 16.9, 29.4, 13.6, 11.1, 8.0, 16.6, 12.0, 13.1, 9.1, 9.7, 21.0, 11.2, 14.4, 18.8, 14.0, 19.9, 12.4, 10.8, 21.6, 15.4, 17.4, 14.8, 22.7, 11.5, 10.5, 11.8, 12.4, 16.6, 11.7, 12.9, 17.8]
```

I found that I need to use gev.fit, so I thought using the following:

```
t = np.linspace(1,43,43)
fit = gev.fit(max_precip,loc=3)
pdf = gev.pdf(t, *fit)
plt.plot(t,pdf)
plt.plot(t, max_precip, "o")
```

But this only prints the points of max_precip in a graph and not the GEV distribution.

Can someone help me? Sorry if this question is already asked, I couldnt find anything like it.

I used these imports:

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from dateutil.rrule import rrule, YEARLY
import datetime
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
from scipy.stats import genextreme as gev
from scipy.stats import genpareto as gpd
from scipy.optimize import minimize
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried to fit your data

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import genextreme as gev

def main(rvs):
    shape, loc, scale = gev.fit(rvs)
    return shape, loc, scale

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rvs = [9.4, 38.0, 12.5, 35.3, 17.6, 12.9, 12.4, 19.6, 15.0, 13.2, 12.3, 16.9, 16.9, 29.4, 13.6, 11.1, 8.0, 16.6, 12.0, 13.1, 9.1, 9.7, 21.0, 11.2, 14.4, 18.8, 14.0, 19.9, 12.4, 10.8, 21.6, 15.4, 17.4, 14.8, 22.7, 11.5, 10.5, 11.8, 12.4, 16.6, 11.7, 12.9, 17.8]

    shape, loc, scale = main(rvs)

    print(shape)
    print(loc)
    print(scale)

    l = loc + scale / shape

    xx = np.linspace(l+0.00001, l+0.00001+35, num=71)
    yy = gev.pdf(xx, shape, loc, scale)

    hist, bins = np.histogram(rvs, bins=12, range=(-0.5, 23.5), density=True)
    plt.bar(bins[:-1], hist, width = 2, align='edge')

    plt.plot(xx, yy, 'ro')
    plt.show()
```

but what I've got back are

```
-0.21989526255575445
12.749780017954315
3.449061347316184
```

for `shape`, `loc` and `scale`. If you look at [GEV distribution as defined in scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.genextreme.html), when shape is negative, the valid interval is [loc + scale/shape...+infinity]. I've computed latter value and it is equal to

```
-2.935417290135696
```

should work...

Python3, Anaconda, scipy 1.1, Windows 10 64bit

UPDATE

Ok, I've updated the code and added plotting, looks somewhat reasonable. Is it what are you looking for? Basically, trick is to histogram it and plot density bins overlapping with PDF

[image]

Comment: If you compare the parametrization given in the wikipedia article with that used by [`genextreme`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.genextreme.html), you'll see that shape parameters have opposite signs.  So the support of the fit that you computed is (loc + scale/shape, +∞) = (-2.9354, +∞).

Comment: Okay, thank you!! I now understand the first part. But the thing I still wonder is where / in which function I have to put the value for the interval in order to get a graph like the one on the docs.scipy.org website you linked to.

Comment: Thank you very much!! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Out of curiosity, I tried the [GeneralizedExtremeValue Factory](https://openturns.github.io/openturns/latest/user_manual/_generated/openturns.GeneralizedExtremeValueFactory.html?highlight=generalizedextreme%20factory#openturns.GeneralizedExtremeValueFactory) (GEV) available in OpenTURNS

```
import openturns as ot
sample = ot.Sample([[p] for p in max_precip])

gev = ot.GeneralizedExtremeValueFactory().buildAsGeneralizedExtremeValue(sample)
print (gev)
>>> GeneralizedExtremeValue(mu=12.7497, sigma=3.44903, xi=0.219894)
```

I can confirm it gives the same result.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for bringing up [OpenTURNS](https://openturns.github.io/openturns/latest/index.html). I was desperately searching for a good library to do EVT distribution fitting. In my case SciPy and OpenTURNS returns different results for the GEV (Type III) distribution. Anyways, may I kindly ask for the code to plot the above figure? Thank you!