# Calculating Return Value using Generalised Extreme Value Distribution (GEV)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statistics, distribution

I have annual temperature data of 30 years and want to calculate **Return Value** of this data using **GEV distribution** for **50 and 100 year** **Return Period**.

My 30 year data:

```
data=[28.01,29.07,28.67,21.57,21.66,24.62,21.45,28.51,22.65,21.57,20.89,20.96,21.05,22.29,20.81,21.08,20.77,23.18,22.98,21.88,21.07,20.74,22.69,22.42,31.81,25.78,29.09,28.11,22.18,21.6]
```

How to find return value using GEV?

Comment: Does not this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52455797/python-fitting-a-gev-distribution-from-these-values

Comment: you need it: from scipy.stats import genextreme as gev

Comment: No, the above links are not helpful, I already tried on  my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To estimate the return level of a given return period T, first estimate the parameters of the generalized extreme value distribution, and then compute the inverse of the survival function at 1/T of the fitted distribution.  (The survival function SF(x) is just 1 - CDF(x).  If you read about computing return levels, you'll typically see the problem stated as solving CDF(x) = 1 - 1/T.  That is the same as solving SF(x) = 1/T.)

Here's a script that uses `scipy.stats.genextreme` to estimate the return levels for your data at several return periods.  The method `genextreme.isf()` is the inverse of the survival function.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import genextreme


data = np.array([28.01, 29.07, 28.67, 21.57, 21.66, 24.62, 21.45, 28.51,
                 22.65, 21.57, 20.89, 20.96, 21.05, 22.29, 20.81, 21.08,
                 20.77, 23.18, 22.98, 21.88, 21.07, 20.74, 22.69, 22.42,
                 31.81, 25.78, 29.09, 28.11, 22.18, 21.6])

# Fit the generalized extreme value distribution to the data.
shape, loc, scale = genextreme.fit(data)
print("Fit parameters:")
print(f"  shape: {shape:.4f}")
print(f"  loc:   {loc:.4f}")
print(f"  scale: {scale:.4f}")
print()

# Compute the return levels for several return periods.
return_periods = np.array([5, 10, 20, 50, 100])
return_levels = genextreme.isf(1/return_periods, shape, loc, scale)

print("Return levels:")
print()
print("Period    Level")
print("(years)   (temp)")

for period, level in zip(return_periods, return_levels):
    print(f'{period:4.0f}  {level:9.2f}')
```

Output:

```
Fit parameters:
  shape: -0.9609
  loc:   21.5205
  scale: 1.0533

Return levels:

Period    Level
(years)   (temp)
   5      25.06
  10      29.95
  20      39.45
  50      67.00
 100     111.53
```

Comment: Thank you, Warren !!, This is what I wanted. Thank you for ur help.

Comment: Can we Change the method of gev fit on data to any other method??

Comment: The method to compute the return levels (i.e. using `genextreme.isf(1/T, shape, loc, scale)`) does not depend on how the parameters were estimated, so if you use some other method to estimate the parameters, you can still compute the return levels the same way.